# android caching image from sdcard

Tags: android

i want to get image from sdcard in listview item i am able to show image but i want to cache that image so that i have smooth scroll can anyone please tell me how to cache image from sdcard i got the code but it show image from drawable but i want from sdcard

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.LruCache;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

        // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception.
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number
                // of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount();
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return items.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView img = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            img = new ImageView(context);
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        } else {
            img = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(items.get(arg0),
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        loadBitmap(resId, img);

        return img;
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty_photo);
            task.execute(resId);
        }
    }

    static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap,
                BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
            super(res, bitmap);
            bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(
                    bitmapWorkerTask);
        }

        public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
            return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
            if (bitmapData != data) {
                // Cancel previous task
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same work is already in progress
                return false;
            }
        }
        // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was
        // cancelled
        return true;
    }

    private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return (Bitmap) mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        public int data = 0;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
            // collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    context.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ankita, that means you want to fetch images from SD Card and want to display it in ListView?

Comment: yes i want to show i am able to show but i want to cache image

Comment: If you getting images from SD Card then why you want to cache the images? because its already saved in SD card then what is the reason t store it again?

Comment: @pratt  i want to get smooth scrolling.. in my listview

Comment: Ya so you will get smooth scroll ofcourse from Sd card as well.

Comment: caching itself will save your images in Sd card, then this approach I dont think so will work.

Comment: wait one sec i will show you the error what i get

Comment: Ya Ankita, this will happen with this ofcourse, because if you generate too many Bitmaps then it will ofcourse show you Outofmemory.

Comment: @pratt help me i get these error what should i do then.............

Comment: Ankita, after your bitmap's work has been done just write, bitmap.recycle(); so it will make clear your Bitmap.

Comment: @pratt can you give me any example please my code is holder.image.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

Comment: This is completely wrong concept dear, this will not get succeded

Comment: Show your images directly from SD Card, that's it. It will work smooth 100%.

Comment: Then also you want to try then after this line :  holder.image.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
bmThumbnail.recycle();
bmThumbnail=null;

Comment: @pratt i am new to programing please give me example na and i want more help can you help me somewhere else

Comment: @AnkitaSingh Did you try implementing lazy loaders like Android Universal Image Loader? There you can pass sdcard path as Uri and lazy load them onto listview etc to get smooth scroll.

Comment: @AnkitaSingh visit this link : http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/aquery-image-loading/

Comment: @pratt Showing images from sdcard directly onto listview will lead to outofmemoryexception if the image size is large, so it is better to cache and load them. And clear cache while exiting the app or activity if you want to release memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use AQuery. Download AQuery jar file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list). Add it into your Build path and then where you want to show your image, just display it like below:

```
AQuery aQuery=new AQuery(this);
File file = new File(YOUR IMAGE PATH);        
aq.id(R.id.avatar).image(file, true,true); // that both true means you caching your images.
```